# Using redis for Geospatial(on stable version)

Tags: java, redis, geolocation, geocoding, geospatial

I am trying to model on Redis a way to get all nearby users for a longitude,latitude inputs.

That means I need to understand how I should Insert key,value to redis and which data-structure I should use

And on the other hand how I should search in redis for nearby Users by a given longtitude,latitude input

I know it's available on Redis 3.2. but we still using the last redis redis (3.0.3)

Thank you,
ray.

So for this input: key: userId value

Comment: Your question is opinion-based, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis geo data is organized within Geo-Sets (backed by sorted sets). The approach by having userIds associated with geo data fits well to the Redis Geo support.

You could maintain one Geo-Set per (domain?/country?) for partitioning reasons. I could not find anything about sorted set size limits. A Redis hash can [contain up to](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes)  `2^32 - 1` field-value pairs and I'm not sure whether this is applicable somehow to sorted sets. So you have one set for simplicity now that is identified by a `key`, and that holds some members that are associated with geo locations:

You `[GEOADD](http://redis.io/commands/geoadd) some-set-name long1 lat1 userId1 long2 lat2 userId2 ... longN latN userIdN` and then the set contains some entries.

**Example**

```
GEOADD key 8.6638775 49.5282537 "Weinheim" 8.3796281 48.9978127 "Office Tower" 8.665351, 49.553302 "Train-Station"
```

The example command adds three places to the Geo-Set identified with `key`.

You can query now using `[GEORADIUS](http://redis.io/commands/georadius) some-set-name long lat radius m|km|ft|mi` to query the set and retrieve all members within the radius around the center of long/lat.

**Example**

```
GEORADIUS key 8.6582861 49.5285695 1 KM
```

The example command queries all elements within a 1 km radius and would return in this case `Weinheim` as the result.

You can query a Geo-Set also by a set member. Means if you use a location that exists within the set, you can use that as reference instead of specifying the geo location using long/lat (example use case: Search all users within the radius of userId X):

`[GEORADIUSBYMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/georadiusbymember) key member radius m|km|ft|mi`

**Example**

```
GEORADIUSBYMEMBER key "Train-Station" 5 KM
```

The result of the command returns the set members within a 5 km radius around `Train-Station`. The resulting elements are: `Train-Station` and `Weinheim`.

[lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) is the first Java client that has native support for all Geo-Commands. You can find [here](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lambdaworks/redis/GeoCommandTest.java) the Unit-Test, which demonstrates the API usage.

Please note that the example commands display just a subset of the Geo features, read more within the Redis docs.

Comment: Just realized that you want to use Geo-Features with 3.0 and not 3.2, sorry, missed that part :(

Comment: Yes. thanks for your response. But I am using the stable version 3.0. and we dont have geo-support over there. I would try 3.2 but I am afraid of using beta-version on production. what do you think?

Comment: 3.2 should be out by ~September... You could implement Geo yourself on top of the sorted sets, much like what Matt and Salvatore did. There are open sources out there that do this or other geo modeling on top of Redis... I would definitely start using 3.2's features if possible rather than develop something of my own (and BTW, if you use unstable and find/report/fix issues - it will be stable sooner ;))

Comment: @mp911de is it possible to set time period for such entry? for example after 30 seconds I want an entry from the geo list to be deleted

Comment: AFAIK - no. You can expire only the whole set (http://redis.io/commands/expire). There's no such thing as ZEXPIRE but feel free to file an issue https://github.com/antirez/redis

Comment: So If I want to "expire" manually a specific item in the set. How would you suggest doing so?

Comment: My solution would be very creative by using another sorted set. So basically the one set contains the userId's to geo location and the other one the userId to expiry timestamp. You would need a timer/job that scans the expiry ZSET and evict the members programatically in both ZSET's

Comment: How would you scan the expiry ZSET? go thru all keys every X interval and compare the timestamp to the current time? and if I have thousands of key's in a time window. is that efficient ?

Comment: Redis provides a range scan http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore and range remove command http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore. You would `ZRANGEBYSCORE key 0 (now-timestamp)` to retrieve all elements to expire, then invoke `ZREM key member1 member2 memberN` to do batch-removal and then either `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` to delete the expiry set members or also `ZREM ...` to remove the members from the other ZSET.